# Format page number in the toc / listoffigures / listofalgorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I have each listing on one single side. Is there any way to format the page number (font size and alignment)? I use the package `fancyhdr` and the following code:

```
\fancyfootoffset[R]{1cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.8cm}
```

That doesn't work. Here I have a little example. Page numbers "IV" and "1" are correct formatted, the numbers of pages above not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,listof=toc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% adjust page numbers horizontally and vertically
\fancyfootoffset[R]{1cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.8cm}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

% clear all header and footers
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\rfoot{\changefont \thepage}

% font
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

% space between two lines and margins of document
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}    

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\listofalgorithms  

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction}
\noindent
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` so that the `plain` style (which is the one used in the first page of TOC, LOF, etc.) is redefined to be the same as the `fancy` one, i.e. the one you've just defined.

Comment: @karlkoeller Should you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @LudovicC. I already answered this question, but I've deleted it. Now undeleting, if you want....

Comment: @Tony Is the karlkoeller's answer satisfying? Could you accept it if so or delete your question if you estimate that it does not have its place here?

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to redefine the `plain` style which is used in section-like pages to reflect your changes:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,listof=toc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% adjust page numbers horizontally and vertically
\fancyfootoffset[R]{1cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.8cm}

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

% clear all header and footers
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule
\rfoot{\changefont \thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

% font
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

% space between two lines and margins of document
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage
\listoftables

\newpage
\listofalgorithms

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction}
\noindent
text
\end{document}
```

Page example:

[image]